# Is it possible to create a method which can be invoked directly from a primitive type variable in java?

Tags: java, methods

Methods which are invoked from an object reference like StringBuilder class's `.append()` method or directly from a class like `Math.pow()` can be easily created.

But is it possible to create a method such as `.toUpperCase()` or `.toLowerCase()` which can be invoked form any string type variable?
A method that can be invoked from a certain primitive type variable.

Comment: No. But FYI, String is not a primitive type, and it already has a toUpperCase() and a toLowerCase() method.

Comment: thanks,it seem your right.I always thought String was one of the primitive type data

Comment: Wrapper types are indeed `final`, so you can't extend them to add your own methods. You have to create static utility methods, which accept the primitive as one of their arguments, i.e. `static boolean isEven(int number) { return number % 2 == 0; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is not a primitive type. Also, the `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` methods are available in Strings.

However, if you're talking about other datatypes like `int`, then if you do want to have some methods then you can convert it to their corresponding non-primitive classes (`Integer` for `int`, `Long` for `long`, `Double` for `double`, `Boolean` for `boolean`, et cetera).

Comment: but wrapper classes are final.So I can't add any more methods in it.

Comment: @RedwanHossainArnob you can't; but you can just define (static) methods in some other class which do what you need, that take the primitive as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` are methods already included in String, that access the string directly.

Somehow if you created a class that contains only a string variable, and a constructor that sets it, you can't simply call `MyStringClass string = "message";`

Here you can try:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass(/*Parameter if exists.*/);
//Or.
myObject.setString();
String string = myObject.getString()/*And another method like toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() if you want*/;
```

And now you have created a string based on a class object.

In the first example, you created a string. Now if you want to influence the string with your own created method, you could use something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  ...

  public static String myStringMethod(/*Pass a string that you want to modify if so.*/){
    return "message";
    //Or based on a parameter.
    return string+=string;//For example;
  }

  //Or using an non-returning method "void".

  public static void myMethod(String string, String string2, String string_ /*You can even pass multiple parameters, separated with commas.*/){
    string = "Hello ";
    string2 = "World!;
    string_ = string+string2;
  }
}
```